# Issue with Twitter streaming API

Tags: scala, twitter, oauth

I'm kind of new to Twitter streaming API. And I'm trying to get [this beautiful and minimalist Scala wrapper for streaming API](https://github.com/acrosa/Scala-TwitterStreamer) to get work.

But unfortunately I end up getting this weird error

```
HttpMethodDirector - Failure authenticating with BASIC 'Firehose'@stream.twitter.com:443
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException: There was a problem connecting, HTTP code received was: 401 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

I checked the Authorization header and it all looks OK to me.

```
oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1, 
oauth_signature -> YVbrIgokxdhbZ1AixdlLGaLWrfw=, 
oauth_consumer_key -> ********************************, 
oauth_version -> 1.0, 
oauth_token -> ********************************************************, 
oauth_timestamp -> 1379582015, 
oauth_nonce -> wKqKGNNCtU2ND1j5xYR0oiTraBrF7i6m
```

The signature generation mechanism is also looks good to me as compared to 
[twitter official doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature)

You can further look [to the actual .scala where the place it get generated](https://github.com/acrosa/Scala-TwitterStreamer/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/streamer/twitter/oauth/OAuth.scala#L52)

Can someone point me out where the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to connect to the Firehose stream which is not publicly available. I work at Gnip and we have the Firehose and provide access to data from it (for a price). You should try connecting to a different method, in the documentation you provided they talk about available methods [here](https://github.com/acrosa/Scala-TwitterStreamer#api-methods).